# Dataframe level computation in pySpark

Tags: pyspark

I am using PySpark and want to use the benefit of multiple nodes to improve on performance time.

For example:

Suppose I have 3 columns and have 1 million records:

```
Emp ID | Salary | % Increase | New Salary 
1 | 200 | 0.05 | 
2 | 500 | 0.15 | 
3 | 300 | 0.25 | 
4 | 700 | 0.1 |
```

I want to compute the New Salary column and want to use the power of multiple nodes in pyspark to reduce overall processing time.

I don't want to do an iterative row wise computation of New Salary.

Does df.withColumn do the computation at a dataframe level? Would it be able to give better performance as more nodes are used?

Answer (score 0):

Spark's dataframes are basically a distributed collection of data. Spark [manages](https://www.dezyre.com/article/how-data-partitioning-in-spark-helps-achieve-more-parallelism/297#:%7E:text=Spark%20automatically%20partitions%20RDDs%20and,Spark%20are%20collection%20of%20partitions.) this distribution and the  [operations](https://www.educba.com/spark-dataframe/) (such as `.withColumn`) on them.

[Here](https://medium.com/swlh/10-ways-to-improve-spark-performance-b54e89b8d83a) is a quick google search on how to increase spark's performance.